# Angular js can't fetching data from ASP.Net Identity default user table

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-identity

In this project,  I'm using AngularJS and asp.net MVC4. I'm trying to get data from the default identity user table but failed, when I try the same code for other tables it works.
This is my code

```
public JsonResult GetAll()
    {
        var q = (from u in db.Users
                 select new
                 {
                     Id = u.Id,
                     Email = u.Email
                 }).ToList();

        return new JsonResult { Data = q, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }

$scope.GetAllRecords = function () {
    $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "Career/GetAll"
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.Data = response.data
    },
    function () {
        alert("error");
    })
}

<div  ng-controller="careerController" data-ng-init="GetAllRecords()">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="Data in Data">
        <td>{{Data.Id}}</td>
        <td>{{Data.Email}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: do you have an error ? script error ?

Comment: no rest of the code is working with other tables but not working for by default ASP.Net Identity user table...-:(

Answer (score 0):

You have user collection in `Data` property. So take out `Data` from `response.data`

```
$scope.Data = response.data.Data
```